# How to find the range of dates from a datetime column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Wondering how to print the range of dates in a dataframe. Seems like it would be very simple but I can't find answers anywhere. Is there an easy way to do this with pandas datetime module?

So if this was a small version of the dataframe for example:

| Date | Id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-09-23 14:00:00 | 4752764 | 12212 |
| 2020-10-25 08:00:00 | 4752764 | 12298 |
| 2020-10-28 12:00:00 | 4752764 | 12291 |
| 2020-10-29 18:00:00 | 4752764 | 12295 |

How could I get an output like:

```
date_range = 2020-09-23 to 2020-10-29
```

**OR**

```
date_range = 23rd of September, 2020 to 29th of October, 2020
```

I appreciate any answers :)

Comment: Take the `.max()` and `.min()`?

Comment: A nice and simple solution for this. Thanks @roganjosh! :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) # If your Date column is of the type object otherwise skip this
date_range = str(df['Date'].dt.date.min()) + ' to ' +str(df['Date'].dt.date.max())
```